# yolov5 and yolov7 of pytorch are mixed use for Different processes inference, and the model loads the wrong folder

Tags: python, pytorch, yolo

yolov5 and yolov7 of pytorch are mixed use for Different processes inference, and the model loads the wrong folder.

I need to use both versions of Yolo V5 and Yolo V7 in one project.
And load the model into different processes.[cpu or GPU]

my code is like:

```py
class v7_infer(Process):
    def __init__(self,opt):
        super().__init__()
        self.darknet = MyYoloDetection_V7.MyYoloDetection(opt)

class v5_infer(Process):
    def __init__(self,opt):
        super().__init__()
        self.opt = opt
        print('start load model...')
        self.darknet = MyYoloDetection_V5.MyYoloDetection(self.opt)

mp.set_start_method(method='spawn')
p1 = v7_infer((opt["detection_config1"]))
sys.path.remove('c:\\code\\video_process\\MyYoloModel\\V7')
p2 = v5_infer(opt["detection_config2"])
    
p1.start()
p2.start()
p1.join()  
p2.join()
```

i got the error like:

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/code/video_process/Backend_flask/testMulti_detect.py", line 93, in <module>
    p2 = v5_infer(opt["detection_component"])
  File "c:/code/video_process/Backend_flask/testMulti_detect.py", line 42, in __init__
    self.darknet = MyYoloDetection_V5.MyYoloDetection(self.opt)
  File "c:\code\video_process\MyYoloModel\V5\MyYoloDetection_V5.py", line 76, in __init__
    self.model = V5_attempt_load(opt["weights"], device=opt['device'])
  File "c:\code\video_process\MyYoloModel\V5\models\experimental.py", line 81, in attempt_load
    ckpt = torch.load(attempt_download(w), map_location='cpu')  # load
  File "C:\Users\WYANING\.conda\envs\yolov5\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 712, in load
    return _load(opened_zipfile, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
  File "C:\Users\WYANING\.conda\envs\yolov5\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 1046, in _load
    result = unpickler.load()
  File "C:\Users\WYANING\.conda\envs\yolov5\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 1039, in find_class
    return super().find_class(mod_name, name)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'C3' on <module 'models.common' from 'c:\\code\\video_process\\MyYoloModel\\V7\\models\\common.py'>
```

I have many questions about this:

1. Why torch \ serialization Torch. Py The load function has a breakpoint but cannot be debugged?
2. Why can't get attribute 'C3' find the right folder by setting the environment variable?
3. How to infer  the two models in a multi process [or under a single GPU]? or like
4. Can different versions of Yolo be used in the same project?

my project structure is like 【V7 and V5 are isolated by folders】：

```
├───MyYoloModel
│   │   camera.py
│   │   yolov5_decetion.py
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   ├───utils
│   │   │   downloads.py
│   │   │   general.py
│   │   │   metrics.py
│   │   │   torch_utils.py
│   │   │   __init__.py
│   │   │
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   │
│   ├───V5
│   │   │   augmentations.py
│   │   │   camera.py
│   │   │   export.py
│   │   │   hubconf.py
│   │   │   MyYoloDetection_V5.py
│   │   │   __init__.py
│   │   │
│   │   ├───models
│   │   │   │   common.py
│   │   │   │   experimental.py
│   │   │   │   tf.py
│   │   │   │   yolo.py
│   │   │   │   yolov5l.yaml
│   │   │   │   yolov5x.yaml
│   │   │   │   __init__.py
│   │   │   │
│   │   │   ├───hub
│   │   │   │       anchors.yaml
│   │   │   │       yolov5s-ghost.yaml
│   │   │   │       yolov5s-transformer.yaml
│   │   │   │       yolov5s6.yaml
│   │   │   │       yolov5x6.yaml
│   │   │   │
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   ├───utils
│   │   │   │   activations.py
│   │   │   │   augmentations.py
│   │   │   │   autoanchor.py
│   │   │   │   autobatch.py
│   │   │   │   benchmarks.py
│   │   │   │   callbacks.py
│   │   │   │   dataloaders.py
│   │   │   │   downloads.py
│   │   │   │   general.py
│   │   │   │   loss.py
│   │   │   │   metrics.py
│   │   │   │   plots.py
│   │   │   │   torch_utils.py
│   │   │   │   __init__.py
│   │   │   │
│   │   │   ├───aws
│   │   │   │       mime.sh
│   │   │   │       resume.py
│   │   │   │       userdata.sh
│   │   │   │       __init__.py
│   │   │   │
│   │   │   ├───docker
│   │   │   │       .dockerignore
│   │   │   │       Dockerfile
│   │   │   │       Dockerfile-arm64
│   │   │   │       Dockerfile-cpu
│   │   │   │
│   │   │   ├───flask_rest_api
│   │   │   │       example_request.py
│   │   │   │       README.md
│   │   │   │       restapi.py
│   │   │   │
│   │   │   ├───google_app_engine
│   │   │   │       additional_requirements.txt
│   │   │   │       app.yaml
│   │   │   │       Dockerfile
│   │   │   │
│   │   │   ├───loggers
│   │   │   │   │   __init__.py
│   │   │   │   │
│   │   │   │   └───wandb
│   │   │   │           log_dataset.py
│   │   │   │           README.md
│   │   │   │           sweep.py
│   │   │   │           sweep.yaml
│   │   │   │           wandb_utils.py
│   │   │   │           __init__.py
│   │   │   │
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───V7
│   │   │   hubconf.py
│   │   │   MyYoloDetection_V7.py
│   │   │   utils.7z
│   │   │
│   │   ├───models
│   │   │   │   common.py
│   │   │   │   experimental.py
│   │   │   │   yolo.py
│   │   │   │   __init__.py
│   │   │   │
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │           common.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   │           experimental.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   │           yolo.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   │           __init__.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   │
│   │   ├───utils
│   │   │   │   activations.py
│   │   │   │   add_nms.py
│   │   │   │   autoanchor.py
│   │   │   │   datasets.py
│   │   │   │   general.py
│   │   │   │   google_utils.py
│   │   │   │   loss.py
│   │   │   │   metrics.py
│   │   │   │   plots.py
│   │   │   │   torch_utils.py
│   │   │   │   __init__.py
│   │   │   │
│   │   │   ├───aws
│   │   │   │       mime.sh
│   │   │   │       resume.py
│   │   │   │       userdata.sh
│   │   │   │       __init__.py
│   │   │   │
│   │   │   ├───google_app_engine
│   │   │   │       additional_requirements.txt
│   │   │   │       app.yaml
│   │   │   │       Dockerfile
│   │   │   │
│   │   │   ├───wandb_logging
│   │   │   │       log_dataset.py
│   │   │   │       wandb_utils.py
│   │   │   │       __init__.py
│   │   │   │
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │           autoanchor.cpython-38.pyc

│   │   └───__pycache__
│   │      
│   │
│   └───__pycache__
```

Comment: Could you resolve this? Resetting them and using them independently works but I couldn't get the hang of it as you did.